# Ember data hasMany records loaded only in the canonicalState property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My application's index route gets data from server using `Ember.$.getJSON(url)` in the route's model hook. The response is then pushed to the store using pushPayload method. When I do `foo.get('bars')` where `foo` has many `bars` (still in the model hook), it results in **empty bars**. Seen from the server's response and the ember inspector though, **the foo's bars actually have some data**. So I investigated the `foo.get('bars')` using chrome's console, and found out **the bar records are loaded in its canonicalState property**. So my workaround is to use `foo.get('bars.canonicalState')` instead.

So far its working good, but since it feels hacky and I can't find the canonicalState property in ember's documentation, I would like to know if this is the right way of doing it? and why does this happen?

Comment: Could you add your `foo` model and the json payload?

Answer (score 0):

In your `controller`, try the following...

```
...
myBars: Ember.computed.map('foo.bars', function(bar) { return bar; }),
...
```

Then you should be able to access `myBars` as a properly constructed array of `bar` objects.